# How to use mysql IN() function in php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Column `state` belongs to `table2` and  consists of the following varchars: `"AL","AK",..`
In my php code I have the following String: `$states="AL,AK,AZ,IL";`
I tried to use it in mySQL query in the following way:

```
$query = SELECT * FROM 'table2' WHERE  'state' IN('$states');
```

It does not show any results... What is the correct syntax for those apostrophes?

Comment: Be careful when putting data directly into a query.  Make sure that those state abbreviations are coming straight from your code, and that you don't use this technique with data that must be escaped.

Comment: As easier alternative (in combination with bound params) you can use `FIND_IN_SET()` instead of the `IN` clause.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason why it is not working is because:

- values in the `IN` statement is not wrap with single quote
- column name and table names are wrap with single quotes when it shouldn't be because they are identifiers not string literals

Try this,

```
$individualStates = explode(",", $states);
$newState = "'" . implode("','", $individualStates) . "'";
$query = "SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE state IN($newState)";
```

when parsed, the output of the statement is,

```
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE state IN('AL','AK','AZ','IL')
```

- [How can I create a prepared statement for IN () operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15991146/491243)

---

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: @JW웃, with empty array you will get empty string.

Comment: @sectus then with empty string, you'll get no result. (*expected because the array is empty*)

Comment: @JW웃, if you have no empty string in your DB. : )

Comment: @JW웃: And I think something should be said here regarding SQL escaping.

Answer (score 5):

This:

```
$states_in = "'" . implode("','", $individualStates) . "'";
```

Is bad. You're opening yourself to SQL injection. Instead, do this:

```
$states = explode(',', $states);
$states_in = array_map(array($instancePDO, 'quote'), $states);
$states_in = implode(',', $states_in);
```

If you prefer to use prepared statements instead, this will give you the placeholder string:

```
$states_placeholder = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($individualStates), '?'));
```

Comment: Thank You fro answer. Do you mean XSS? I use only `<select>` tags...So that must exclude possibility of any injection. I do not use `<input>` Or is there still possibility for injection?‎

Answer (score 3):

```
$states = explode(',', $states);
$states = array_map(function($value){return "'$value'";}, $states);
$query = "SELECT * FROM `table2` WHERE  `state` IN(".implode(',', $states).")";
```

But better to use prepared statement. [Read relative question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/php-pdo-can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition).